# Gitlab CI/CD: "needs" not working in .gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, cicd, gitlab-ci.yml

I am using needs in .gitlab-ci.yml to run a job say job3 when either job1 and job2 are success or when either of jobs, job1 or job2 are failed. Below is my code

```
stages:
 - job1
 - job2
 - job3


job1:
  script: 
        ----some code

job2:
  script:
        ----some code
job3:
  script:
        ----some code

  needs: [job1 & job2, !job1 | !job2]
```

Can someone guide me on this?

Comment: Under what condition would you not want it to run?

Comment: hi @luk2302, as I have mentioned. I want job3 to run when job1 and job2 are both success or either of job1 and job2 fails.

Comment: So only if both fail do you not want to run?

Comment: job1 runs before job2, when job1 fails I want to trigger job3 to run without executing job2.

job1 is success but job2 fails, I want job3 to run.

finaly, if job1 is success, and job2 is success then job3 should run.

Comment: Hope I have made my self clear. there are basically three conditions. 

1) Job1 fail, dont run job2 run job3 instead.
2) job1 success, job2 fail, run job3
3) job1 success, job2 success run job3